# Macro función TIMESTAMPDIFF de FireDAC con Oracle y SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, delphi, oracle-19c

Me encuentro trabajando con Delphi XE7 con FireDAC y con conexión a Oracle 19c y SQL Server, probando la macro función TIMESTAMPDIFF con fracciones de segundos, segundos, minutos y horas, veo que con Oracle solo lo realiza en fechas es decir si envió una fecha con tiempo, el tiempo es ignorado y solo me devuelve la diferencia en cuestiones de días completos, por ejemplo:

```
SELECT TIMESTAMPDIFF(FRAC_SECOND,'2020-09-14 18:28:29.3654','2020-09-15 18:30:30.3654') FROM PEOPLE;

Result Oracle:86400000000
Result SQL Server:86521000000
```

¿Saben de alguna manera de hacer que FireDAC si tome en cuenta el tiempo con Oracle para obtener la diferencia de estos?

Comment: ¿Has intentado con `second` y no `frac_second`? ¿Has visto qué es lo que recibe oracle en este caso?

Comment: Si, si he intentado con second y sucede exactamente lo mismo, me calcula los segundos pero con base a los días completos, en la unidad fireDac.Phys.OracleMeta están las sentencias por las que cambia el timestampdiff

Comment: Y ¿cuáles son esas? ¿Qué está llegando a la DB?

Comment: A la BD llega SELECT TRUNC(('2020-10-20 18:15:20.656')-('2020-10-17 20:08:20.6789'))* (24.0*60.0*1000000)) FROM DUAL;. Esto me devolvió el error de tipos de datos inconsistentes se esperaba number se ha obtenido interval, para efectos de prueba le agregué un TO_DATE a las fechas quitando el tiempo y así ya fue como pude ver qué saca la diferencia en días y lo multiplica por los demás valores

Comment: La expresión que me das da error. Si ejecuto esto en el oracle live: `SELECT TRUNC((to_date('2020-09-14 18:28:29', 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS') - to_date('2020-09-15 18:30:30', 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS')) * 24 * 3600 * 1000000) FROM DUAL;` obtengo un resultado de `-86520999999`, que parece bastante cercano a lo que tu esperas.

Comment: Puedes utilizar el SQL Monitor de firedac o la auditoría de la DB para ver exactamente lo que llega al motor, pero no es la sentencia que me has dado.

Comment: Y los milisegundos? Es que con date solo llega a segundos:(

Comment: Para los segundos me llega así SELECT TRUNC((('2020-09-17 15:16:20.5246')-('2020-09-14 18:30:29.3654))*(24.0*60.0*60.0)) from dual;

Comment: Para ese caso me devuelve el error número no válido